# Property "currentViewController" that can hold objects of different classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a property called currentViewController, that will hold either a UITableViewController or a UIViewController, depending on which child view is active. How do I declare the variable so it can hold both types of classes, or how can I redefine it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so if you declare as `UIViewController` you can hold both.

Comment: Or maybe declase as id and introspect to typecast accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Declaring as UIViewController did the trick. The tip about declaring as id will also be useful, and some googling brought me to [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Dynamic_Binding_and_Typing_with_the_id_Type) page detailing "dynamic typing" and "dynamic binding". Thanks!